# Extract Specific Data in Nested Dictionary-List and write onto Json List

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, nested

I have nested data that need to extract some data from it. Due to in-depth level of the nested data..I'm not able to extract all the data require. For this questions I just focus on how to get all the data requires for object node.

So far I have extract key 'id' value only...in the nested data got some other key of 'tp-id', 'ip' and 'mac' that I need to get the values also...but I still not able to get it....

This is the raw data (source data to collect the data)

```
{
  "network-topology": {
    "topology": [
      {
        "node": [
          {
            "opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-ref": "/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1']",
            "node-id": "openflow:1",
            "termination-point": [
              {
                "opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref": "/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1:2']",
                "tp-id": "openflow:1:2"
              },
              {
                "opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref": "/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1:1']",
                "tp-id": "openflow:1:1"
              },
              {
                "opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref": "/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1:LOCAL']",
                "tp-id": "openflow:1:LOCAL"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "host-tracker-service:addresses": [
              {
                "first-seen": 1562655393902,
                "ip": "10.0.0.1",
                "mac": "00:00:00:00:00:01",
                "id": 6,
                "last-seen": 1562655393902
              }
            ],
            "host-tracker-service:id": "00:00:00:00:00:01",
            "host-tracker-service:attachment-points": [
              {
                "active": true,
                "corresponding-tp": "host:00:00:00:00:00:01",
                "tp-id": "openflow:1:1"
              }
            ],
            "node-id": "host:00:00:00:00:00:01",
            "termination-point": [
              {
                "tp-id": "host:00:00:00:00:00:01"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-ref": "/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2']",
            "node-id": "openflow:2",
            "termination-point": [
              {
                "opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref": "/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2:LOCAL']",
                "tp-id": "openflow:2:LOCAL"
              },
              {
                "opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref": "/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2:1']",
                "tp-id": "openflow:2:1"
              },
              {
                "opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref": "/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2:2']",
                "tp-id": "openflow:2:2"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "host-tracker-service:addresses": [
              {
                "first-seen": 1562655393906,
                "ip": "10.0.0.2",
                "mac": "00:00:00:00:00:02",
                "id": 7,
                "last-seen": 1562655393906
              }
            ],
            "host-tracker-service:id": "00:00:00:00:00:02",
            "host-tracker-service:attachment-points": [
              {
                "active": true,
                "corresponding-tp": "host:00:00:00:00:00:02",
                "tp-id": "openflow:2:1"
              }
            ],
            "node-id": "host:00:00:00:00:00:02",
            "termination-point": [
              {
                "tp-id": "host:00:00:00:00:00:02"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "link": [
          {
            "link-id": "host:00:00:00:00:00:01/openflow:1:1",
            "destination": {
              "dest-node": "openflow:1",
              "dest-tp": "openflow:1:1"
            },
            "source": {
              "source-tp": "host:00:00:00:00:00:01",
              "source-node": "host:00:00:00:00:00:01"
            }
          },
          {
            "link-id": "openflow:2:1/host:00:00:00:00:00:02",
            "destination": {
              "dest-node": "host:00:00:00:00:00:02",
              "dest-tp": "host:00:00:00:00:00:02"
            },
            "source": {
              "source-tp": "openflow:2:1",
              "source-node": "openflow:2"
            }
          },
          {
            "link-id": "openflow:1:2",
            "destination": {
              "dest-node": "openflow:2",
              "dest-tp": "openflow:2:2"
            },
            "source": {
              "source-tp": "openflow:1:2",
              "source-node": "openflow:1"
            }
          },
          {
            "link-id": "openflow:2:2",
            "destination": {
              "dest-node": "openflow:1",
              "dest-tp": "openflow:1:2"
            },
            "source": {
              "source-tp": "openflow:2:2",
              "source-node": "openflow:2"
            }
          },
          {
            "link-id": "openflow:1:1/host:00:00:00:00:00:01",
            "destination": {
              "dest-node": "host:00:00:00:00:00:01",
              "dest-tp": "host:00:00:00:00:00:01"
            },
            "source": {
              "source-tp": "openflow:1:1",
              "source-node": "openflow:1"
            }
          },
          {
            "link-id": "host:00:00:00:00:00:02/openflow:2:1",
            "destination": {
              "dest-node": "openflow:2",
              "dest-tp": "openflow:2:1"
            },
            "source": {
              "source-tp": "host:00:00:00:00:00:02",
              "source-node": "host:00:00:00:00:00:02"
            }
          }
        ],
        "topology-id": "flow:1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

From here I want to have Node - id, tpid, ip and mac... and so far only got id.

Please find below the code I used to get the id value.. I tried to get tpid for example using for loop but i stuck also....

```
#Extract nodes info
node_list = []
for nodes in restData["network-topology"]["topology"][0]["node"]:
    node = {}
    node['id'] = nodes['node-id']
    #for port in nodes['termination-point']:
        #node['tpid'] = port['tp-id']
    node_list.append(node)
nodes_list1 = [dd['id'] for dd in node_list]
print nodes_list1

#Add nodes_list1 info onto networkx
graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_nodes_from(nodes_list1)

#Write onto json file
d = json_graph.node_link_data(graph)
with open('mytopo.json', 'w') as fc:
    json.dump(d, fc, indent=4)
```

This is the output of mytopo.json

```
{
    "directed": false,
    "graph": {},
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id": "host:00:00:00:00:00:02"
        },
        {
            "id": "openflow:1"
        },
        {
            "id": "openflow:2"
        },
        {
            "id": "host:00:00:00:00:00:01"
        }
    ],
    "links": [],
    "multigraph": false
}
```

I would like to have tpid, ip and mac to be in the json file...I expect to have mytopo.json as follows

```
{
  "directed": false,
  "graph": {

  },
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "host:00:00:00:00:00:01",
      "tpid": "host:00:00:00:00:00:01",
      "ip": "10.0.0.1",
      "mac": "00:00:00:00:00:01"
    },
    {
      "id": "openflow:1",
      "tpid": [
        "openflow:1:2",
        "openflow:1:1",
        "openflow:1:LOCAL"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "openflow:2",
      "tpid": [
        "openflow:2:LOCAL",
        "openflow:2:1",
        "openflow:2:2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "host:00:00:00:00:00:02",
      "tpid": "host:00:00:00:00:00:02",
      "ip": "10.0.0.2",
      "mac": "00:00:00:00:00:02"
    }
  ],
  "links": [

  ],
  "multigraph": false
}
```

Appreciate your experts help and guideline for me to proceed further. Thank you.

---

I update for loop as per input @Tim Seed but it only return last tpid value. Based on the source raw data,  tpid value of openflow1 and openflow2 have 3 values while host:00:00:00:00:00:01 and  host:00:00:00:00:00:02 only have 1 value of tpid... so it should return something like below

```
nodes": [
    {
      "id": "host:00:00:00:00:00:01",
      "tpid": "host:00:00:00:00:00:01",
      "ip": "10.0.0.1",
      "mac": "00:00:00:00:00:01"
    },
    {
      "id": "openflow:1",
      "tpid": [
        "openflow:1:2",
        "openflow:1:1",
        "openflow:1:LOCAL"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "openflow:2",
      "tpid": [
        "openflow:2:LOCAL",
        "openflow:2:1",
        "openflow:2:2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "host:00:00:00:00:00:02",
      "tpid": "host:00:00:00:00:00:02",
      "ip": "10.0.0.2",
      "mac": "00:00:00:00:00:02"
    }
  ],
```

when i print node['tpid']... it will show all the tpid as follows

```
openflow:1:2
openflow:1:1
openflow:1:LOCAL
host:00:00:00:00:00:01
openflow:2:LOCAL
openflow:2:1
openflow:2:2
host:00:00:00:00:00:02
```

but it just only add 1 tpid each onto node_list...
    nodes_list1 = [(dd['id'], dd['tpid']) for dd in node_list]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... and expand on it

```
node_list = []
for nodes in restData["network-topology"]["topology"]:
    for sub in nodes["node"]:
        node = {}
        node['id'] = sub['node-id']
        for port in sub['termination-point']:
            node['tpid'] = port['tp-id']            
        node_list.append(node)
```

It should output

```
[{'id': 'openflow:1', 'tpid': 'openflow:1:LOCAL'},
 {'id': 'host:00:00:00:00:00:01', 'tpid': 'host:00:00:00:00:00:01'},
 {'id': 'openflow:2', 'tpid': 'openflow:2:2'},
 {'id': 'host:00:00:00:00:00:02', 'tpid': 'host:00:00:00:00:00:02'}]
```

Comment: Hi sir... i test it but tpid for 'openflow:1' and 'openflow:2' should have 3 values of tpid... for example here.... {
      "id": "openflow:1",
      "tpid": [
        "openflow:1:2",
        "openflow:1:1",
        "openflow:1:LOCAL"
      ]
    }, seems the for loop just read the last tpid

Comment: Why.....It just return only single tpid, does not return all tpid available in the data